# React native navigation.push is not updating the UI from the params

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react navigation 5,

The navigations is like this

```
Home
-->List
   -->detailsA
   -->detailsB
   -->detailsC
   -->detailsD
```

As you can see I got the navigation structure like the above,

I go from `home` component to `list` component using `navigation.navigate`

Its working fine. Also I can go from `List` to `detailsA` using `navigation.navigate`.

Here is the code `List to details`

```
<TouchableOpacity
        key={info.id}
        onPress={() =>
        navigation.navigate('CaseDetails', {
        screen: 'CaseDetails',
            params: {
                random: Math.floor(Math.random()* 2000),
                title: info.title,
                summary: info.summary,
                image: info.image,
            },
        })
    }>
```

As you can see I can pass the info of details using params.

The problem start when I want to go from `details` to `details` page.
As the document stated, I am using `navigation.push` when going from `detailA` to `detailsB`
[React Native](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/)

also passing the of detailsB at the same time.

The code is like this

```
<TouchableOpacity
                key={item.id}
                onPress={() =>
                   //********** using push here
                    navigation.push('CaseDetails', {
                        screen: 'CaseDetails',
                        params: {
                            random: Math.floor(Math.random()* 2000),
                            title: item.title,
                            summary: item.summary,
                            image: item.image,
                            
                    })
                }>
```

As you can see in the code. I am passing new `title , summary and imag`e into the details component but the UI is not updating.

Is there anything I am missing here

The important point is that If I went from `list` to `details A`, Assuming that randomly generate number is `555` , If I go from `detailsA`to `detailsB` the random number is still `555`

Comment: how do you manage the state in your component?

Comment: I don't have state in the details page, I only got the params from using
`const {title,summary} = route.params;`

Comment: The thing is the data from `route.params` always return the `initial values` which is `detailsA`,
Even I passed the value `via params` when going from `detailsA to detailsB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you navigating from detailsA to detailsB just to change its params? If yes, you can just use the function:

```
navigation.setParams({//new params here});
```